# @Html.DisplayFor changed to @Html.EditorFor when the Edit link is clicked for inline editing of row of data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, inline-editing

In default MVC project VS2013, when the data is displayed in table there are options for Edit | Delete | Details. When the Edit link is clicked, the row of data is rendered on another page for Editing.

But I've to change the **label to textbox** when the `@Html.ActionLink` for Edit is clicked i.e change `@Html.DisplayFor` to `@Html.EditorFor` . How can I do that? **I am trying to edit the the data in the row without rendering to another page.**

```
//<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student)  
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.course)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: What label? What textbox? Are you trying to edit the item without redirecting to an edit page? (in which case you need ajax)

Comment: if you are trying to change the  label from student into a text box then want a magic link that goes into the database and changes that students name that is crazy.  You have to create the controller action , pass the id of the student , pass the new string , then write all the logic to connect everything together with ajax.    These prebuilt views the Visual Studios gives you is supposed to give you a start , not be used as is

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes, I am trying to edit the item without redirecting to an edit page.

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for how you might implement the client side behavior. Then you will need javascript/jquery and use ajax to post the edited values to your controller.